# JSONObject cannot be converted into JSONArray

Tags: java, php, android, json

I've been trying to pass a String value from PHP to Android using JSON.

```
{"address":"Lebuh Bandar Utama, Bandar Utama,
            47800 Petaling Jaya, Selangor, Malaysia"}
{"address":"Jalan Pasar, Taman Bunga Kenanga,
            31000 Batu Gajah, Perak, Malaysia"}
{"address":"Jalan 1\/38a, Taman Sri Sinar,
            51200 Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia"}
```

And following code to retrieve the String.

```
try {
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        Log.i("log_tag","name: "+json_data.getString("address"));
        //Get an output to the screen
        a.add(json_data.getString("address"));
    }
}
catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

The error is "JSONObject cannot be converted into JSONArray". Please shed some light and thanks in advance.

Comment: your json is not valid check it in jslint

Comment: First, this has been answered numerous times on SO ... will pick a dup. Second, you don't even have valid JSON; *nothing* you do will make that parse.

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8018931/jsonobject-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9499629/android-jsonobject-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray?rq=1 or ...

Comment: @user3153745 it showing :SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data not valid format

Comment: check here http://json.parser.online.fr/  your json string which you want to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For converting to JSON ARRAY, you should have json address format like below:

```
{
    "address":
    [
        {"Lebuh Bandar Utama, Bandar Utama,
            47800 Petaling Jaya, Selangor, Malaysia"},
        {"Jalan Pasar, Taman Bunga Kenanga,
            31000 Batu Gajah, Perak, Malaysia"},
        {"Jalan 1\/38a, Taman Sri Sinar,
            51200 Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia"}
    ]
}
```

Then your code will be like below:

```
try{
    JSONObject obj= new JSONObject(result);
    JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("address");

    //DO ANYTHING WITH jARRAY NOW
}
catch(JSONException e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
}
```

Then you can convert Address to `JSONARRAY`..

Hope it will help you..!!!

Comment: i have same problem ............now i have use your code where i found result ask to create local variable can i define local variable in this case .......

Comment: i have use    arraylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
         String url="http://thelinejunk.com/mobileapi//locationlistdata.php";
           
         jsonobject =  JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL(url);  
            try {
             
               String address = null;

Comment: jsonobject= new JSONObject(address);
               jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray(address);
                
              for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
                       HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    jsonobject = new JSONObject("result");

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a valid json

You can check here

http://jsonlint.com/

`{` represents a json object node

`[` represents a json array node

If result is a valid json and is a `JSONObject` then

```
JSONObject jsonobect = new JSONObject(result)
```

Or your json looks something like

```
[ // json array node
    {  // json object node
        "address": "Lebuh Bandar Utama, Bandar Utama,47800 Petaling Jaya, Selangor, Malaysia"
    },
    {
        "address": "Jalan Pasar, Taman Bunga Kenanga,31000 Batu Gajah, Perak, Malaysia"
    },
    {
        "address": "Jalan 1/38a, Taman Sri Sinar,51200 Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia"
    }
]
```

or something like

```
{ // json object node
    "addresses": [ // json array of addresses
        { // json object node
            "address": "Lebuh Bandar Utama, Bandar Utama,47800 Petaling Jaya, Selangor, Malaysia"
        },
        {
            "address": "Jalan Pasar, Taman Bunga Kenanga,31000 Batu Gajah, Perak, Malaysia"
        },
        {
            "address": "Jalan 1/38a, Taman Sri Sinar,51200 Kuala Lumpur, Federal Territory of Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is correct ... if the OP even had a valid JSON Object.

Comment: @BrianRoach yup i realized it now op has not posted a valid json

Answer (score 0):

JsonArray representation is [{JSONObject},{JSONOBject}] but you have {JSONOBject}{JSONOBject}, so you don't have jsonArray